# What are some examples of a sequential-decision tasks?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, sequential, nonsequential

I ask this because I'm currently learning about Neural Networks as a subset of the machine learning algorithms

Just trying to get some intuition on what sort of problems out there are categorized as "sequential" while others "non-sequential"

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great example of a non-intuitive sequential decision problem (with a nice and neat solution), is the Pandora search problem:

Paper Link:

http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/31303/MIT-EL-78-008-05532979.pdf?sequence=1

You can read only the Example paragraph on the 5th and 6th pages to get the main idea.